# C sscanf: why is this segfaulting?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I'm trying to take tokens in a format of "%i / %i%s" and split them into three variables.

```
char char1[20];
int int1;
int int2;


sscanf(token, "%[^/]/%d", char1, &int2);
printf("%s - %i ", char1, &int2);
```

It just segfaults.  What am I doing wrong?

I've tried changing %d to %i, with no difference.

Comment: Note: Good idea to limit scanning into string and check results.  `if (sscanf(token, "%19[^/]/%d", char1, &int2) != 2) Handle_ScanFailure();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't print address of int2 in your printf. This is working for me:

```
const char *token = "qwerasdf/10";
char char1[20];
int int2;

sscanf(token, "%[^/]/%d", char1, &int2);
printf("%s - %i ", char1, int2);
```

Output:

```
qwerasdf - 10
```

Comment: Say I have the format "%i/%i/%s".  How should sscanf be formatted?

Comment: `sscanf(token, "%i/%i/%s", &i1, &i2, s);`

Comment: That matches what I have.  Thank you!

Comment: Use a length modifier with any `%s` or `%[` to prevent buffer overflows